# Resource or reference for translatation of Quran in hindi?

Tags: quran, quran-translation

I want to understand verses of Quran. I an not good Arabic as I'm an Asian not generally aware about a Arabic. I can read Arabic because I have completed Quran Sharif. Please help really want to read translation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for online resources then just go to https://quran.com.

Open any surah you want to read.

Click on the settings on the top right corner of the screen.

Click on the translations.

Select Hindi - Suhel Farooq Khan.

Done.

If you got android phone then download Quran Hindi from below link.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tos.quranhindi&hl=en-ca

If you want a pdf file then

https://archive.org/details/QuranMajeedKaAsaanHindiTarjuma-IslamicHindiQuran.pdf

OR

https://archive.org/details/QuranHindi.pdf